# PHP Calendar display every month once

Tags: php, sql

I'm creating a calendar using PHP and MySQL. 
 
I already got it working so you can delete, edit and create new birthdays. 
But now I can't figure out how to make every month only been shown once, and letting the other days in that month come underneath the first time that month has shown.

Does anyone know how to get this working?

```
<h1>Calendar</h1>

<ul>


<?php

$month = array("January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"); 

foreach($birthdays as $Birthday){

    ?>
    <h1><ul><?=$month[$Birthday["month"]-1];?></ul></h1>
    <h2><ul><?=$Birthday["day"];?></ul></h2>
    <a href="<?= URL?>birthday/edit/<?=$Birthday['id'];?>"><ul><?=$Birthday["person"];?> <a href="<?= URL?>birthday/delete/<?= $Birthday['id'] ?>" onclick= "return confirm ('Are you sure you want to delete this birthday??');">x</a></ul></a><br>


<?php }?>


<p><a href="create">Add</a></p>
```

Comment: Within a `ul` element you need a `li` element. Where is the `$birthdays` array defined?

Comment: ul is not underline, it means "unordered list"

Comment: a table would be an easier way to display this. Or use one of the many pre-existing calendar plugins available for free online, which would save a lot of hassle.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your `$month` in a temporary variable and check if the current `$month` is diffrent.

```
$_month = null;
foreach($birthdays as $Birthday){
    if($_month != $Birthday["month"]){
        $_month = $Birthday["month"];
        echo sprintf("<li><h1>%s</h1></li>", $month[$Birthday["month"]-1]);
    }
    // Other output
}
```